# .Net Core IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, asp.net-core

I want to build an identity db context. I have installed the required packages but it is giving me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Use the full path include namespace.  Either AuthContext : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext or AuthContext : Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext

Comment: Did you inject in startup service? 
`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

Comment: You can write the full path to specify `IdentityDbContext`  in which package to use

Comment: The error you are getting is not related to `dll package installation` rather, it saying you have another same class containing the same name. Please [`download the official sample project from here`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/samples/IdentitySample.DefaultUI/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs). In addition, you could [`check the document as well`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-app-with-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a empty project then right click on the project and select scaffold Identity:

[image]

Then you could try with the full path in picture,If you have other problems ,you could also check this project and compare to your project

[image]